# How to Find a Last column in excel and copy in VB.Net

Tags: copy, find

I have two excelsheets Sheet1 and Sheet2 both in the same excel workbook. In sheet1 I have
the following data as in Picture1.
[image: Picture 1]
I just want to copy column A, columnB and the total, to sheet2.
In VBA I used this code.Which is working fine but the problem arises when I convert this to
VB.Net

```
Sub VBA()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2:B4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

In VB.Net I am using this code to copy data from sheet1 to sheet2.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsheet, xlsheet2 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lCol As Long = 0
    Dim xlsourceRange, xlDestRange As Excel.Range
    with xlApp
    .visible = True
    xlwb = .workbooks.open("D:\test.xlsx")
    xlsheet = xlwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    xlsheet2 = xlwb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    xlSourceRange = xlSheet.Range("A2:B2000")'This is copies Column A and Column B
    xlDestRange = xlsheet2.Range("A2")
    xlSourceRange.Copy(xlDestRange)

    End with
    End Sub
    End Class
```

The real problem is to copy the total which is in column I as in picture1. I can't copy it to sheet2 because data is not fixed in sheet1 it is incremental towards the right. I mean in present senario I have six customer from column c to H and the total is in column I. But if there is an addition of two more customer the Total column moves from column I to column K. Any help in this is really appriciated.

Manny Thanks to Kevin from MSDN for finding time to answer this question.
From Kenvin.
Start off note, things were not so simple as explained below.

Okay, from the file you presented I thought it would be simple to get the totals (not sure which one you wanted in the column) or simply the last one (13,886). Using automation last column failed because column S is the last column as per Excel and the last row report by Excel is 2628. Long story short I used a guess to get at the last row/column using the first SQL statement below (SELECT TOP *8), incremented these values to be one based. If the last part worked I then select data where the total column does not have empty cell values which of course removes rows above Total so later on I take care of this. When reading cell values in the total column I take cells with negative values which are seen as strings and convert them to rare negative values then store them as strings as we cannot get regular text values together with numeric values (but you can tweak my logic to do so). Any ways in the end a DataTable has two columns we care about row index and value. Using Row index and value you have column totals and row total.

What I did not do is the actual copy to the other sheet. Lastly, when seeing data like this the expectation is when finding what the actual last row/column was and mixture of data I pretty much knew there was going to be a fair amount of code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
            {
                .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "WS_1.xlsx"),
                .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
            }
        Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=No;")
        Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With
                {
                    .Connection = cn,
                    .CommandText = "SELECT Top 8 * FROM [Customer$]"
                }
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
                Dim FoundRow As Int32 = -1
                Dim FoundCol As Int32 = -1
                For Row As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    For Col As Int32 = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                        If dt.Rows(Row).Item(Col).ToString = "Total" Then
                            FoundRow = Row + 1
                            FoundCol = Col + 1
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
                If FoundRow > -1 Then
                    dt = New DataTable
                    cmd.CommandText = <SQL>SELECT F<%= FoundCol %> FROM [Customer$]  WHERE Not IsNull(F<%= FoundCol %>) </SQL>.Value
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
                    Dim NewTable As New DataTable With {.TableName = "MyTable"}
                    NewTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Identifier", .DataType = GetType(Int32), .AutoIncrement = True, .AutoIncrementSeed = 1})
                    NewTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "RowIndex", .DataType = GetType(Int32)})
                    NewTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Value", .DataType = GetType(String)})
                    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                        Dim Temp As String = row.Item(0).ToString.TrimStart
                        If Temp.StartsWith("(") Then
                            Temp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Temp, "[)(,]", "")
                            Dim Value As Int32 = 0
                            If Int32.TryParse(Temp, Value) Then
                                Value = Value * -1
                                Console.WriteLine(Value)
                                NewTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Value.ToString})
                            Else
                                NewTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Value.ToString})
                            End If
                        Else
                            NewTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Temp})
                        End If
                    Next
                    Dim xrow As DataRow
                    For i As Int32 = 1 To FoundRow - 1
                        xrow = NewTable.NewRow
                        NewTable.Rows.InsertAt(xrow, 0)
                    Next
                    For i As Int32 = 0 To NewTable.Rows.Count - 1
                        NewTable.Rows(i).SetField(Of Int32)("RowIndex", i)
                    Next
                    Console.WriteLine()
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("Did not find a column with Total.")
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Code Module.

```
Module ExcelExtensions
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Will be used in next article I wrote
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Index"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function ExcelColumnName(ByVal Index As Integer) As String
        Dim chars = New Char() _
            {
                "A"c, "B"c, "C"c, "D"c, "E"c, "F"c, "G"c, "H"c, "I"c,
                "J"c, "K"c, "L"c, "M"c, "N"c, "O"c, "P"c, "Q"c, "R"c,
                "S"c, "T"c, "U"c, "V"c, "W"c, "X"c, "Y"c, "Z"c
            }
        Index -= 1
        Dim columnName As String
        Dim quotient = Index \ 26
        If quotient > 0 Then
            columnName = ExcelColumnName(quotient) + chars(Index Mod 26)
        Else
            columnName = chars(Index Mod 26).ToString()
        End If
        Return columnName
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to get a total for columns C to ? where ? means an unspecified column which can change from time to time. If you insert this formula into cell G3 it will return the sum of cells C3:F3. Or if you put it into R7 it will give you the sum of C7:Q7.

```
rg.Formula = "=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3)&"":""&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))"
```

Comment: Source column is not fixed. But destination column is fixed. I am trying to get the last column which is total from sheet1 to sheet2 column C.

Comment: So you want to copy and paste as values? RangeSource.Copy > RangeDest.PasteSpecial...